# Get full path from FileSystem

Tags: java, path, filesystems

I want to get the full path for a `FileSystem` which I created like this.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get(folder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath(), "test.zip"), null);
```

Whatever I tried until now only got me an output like `/` and thats it, but what i really need to get is:

```
C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/junit9210120109362016454/Parent/test.zip/
```

Is there any way to get this information from the `FileSystem` object? I know I could just take the parameter I used to create it in the first place, but I want to be sure I don't mix anything up and I think it's better like that for a unit-test

Based on the accepted answer I came up with this to solve my problem:
`Paths.get(fs.toString(), "file.txt").toString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use
`Path` from `java.nio.file.Path;`

```
Path path = Paths.get(directory.toString());
String fullpath=path.toUri().toString()
```

which will give full path like `file:///F:/somedir1/somdir2/17f5b00a-bd6e-4109-8ce5-85df79b51a00.jpg`

Comment: looks like a good start. `jar:file:///C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/junit8765276587293140985/test.zip!/file.txt` besides the `!` behind the zip file its okay